# Graphic does not show in Jupyter fresh install under conda and using viewscad upstream example

Tags: python, jupyter, conda, openscad

Here is the environment to reproduce the issue in Debian 9 (I had to add lib3mf1_1.8.1+ds-3_amd64.deb, lib3mf-dev_1.8.1+ds-3_amd64.deb, itstool_2.0.5-2_all.deb which are not in the repository with `dpkg -i` and `apt install -f`):

```
# install openscad
cd /opt
git clone git://github.com/openscad/openscad.git
cd openscad
git submodule update --init
sudo ./scripts/uni-get-dependencies.sh
./scripts/check-dependencies.sh # lib3mf was missing
qmake openscad.pro
make # itstool was missing
cp /opt/openscad/openscad /usr/local/bin/
# setup a conda environment and install jupyterlab, solidpython, viewscad
conda create --name cad python=3
conda activate cad
conda install -y -n cad jupyterlab
pip install solidpython
pip install viewscad
# for jupyterlab:
conda install -c conda-forge -n cad nodejs
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

Then run jupyter (jupyter-notebook here)

```
jupyter-notebook
```

Start a python project in jupyter opened in the browser, and input in the first cell:

```
from solid import *
import viewscad
r = viewscad.Renderer()
#r = viewscad.Renderer(openscad_exec='/opt/openscad')
c = cylinder(r = 5, h = 2)
r.render(c)
```

Result is:

```
VBox(children=(HTML(value=''), Renderer(background='#cccc88', background_opacity=0.0, camera=PerspectiveCamera…
```

Instead of showing the graph like in the simplified upstream example [here](https://github.com/nickc92/ViewSCAD/).

If I specify the path of openscad in the `renderer` call like proposed [here](https://pypi.org/project/viewscad/) and in the commented line above, it is the same.

If I test another script with `numpy`, but not `viewscad, solidscad, openscad`, figures are shown. openscad and solidscad on their own are working. So, I guess my problem is related to my viewscad setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem an took me a time to realize I had not installed `pythreejs` correctly. Try running whatever prompt you are using as administrator and going over the full installation of `pythreejs`.

```
pip install pythreejs
jupyter nbextension install --py --symlink --sys-prefix pythreejs
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix pythreejs
```

This solved it for me, used the anaconda prompt.